# Pass variable to UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameter-passing

I try to pass `Package` variable to my UserControl:

```
<uc:Template ID="Template" runat="server" Package="<%=TemplateParams.SimpleSearch %>" />
```

but with no luck - in UC it gives me `<%=TemplateParams.SimpleSearch %>` string instead of `SimpleSearch` parameter from `TemplateParams` class.

How to do this ?

Edit:

About code behind way I know - I would like to know how to do it from view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the user control that holds the property you're attempting to expose you can set the `BrowsableAttribute` attribute:

```
[BrowsableAttribute(true)]
public string myProperty { get; set; }
```

This should expose it in the xml version of the control.

**Edit**
If your `TemplateParams.SimpleSearch` is a string, then you should be able to do the following:

```
Package='<%=TemplateParams.SimpleSearch%>'
```

The `'` makes the difference here. If it is an object, you'll have to do it in the code behind.

Comment: It does not resolve problem - still `Package` contains `<%=TemplateParams.SimpleSearch %>` string.

Answer (score 0):

From code behind you can pass variable or set properties

```
Template.variable="foo";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Page.FindControl("Template").Attributes.Add("Package", "YourValueGoesHere");
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, if you really want to do it in the markup is to use an [expression builder](https://web.archive.org/web/20210304125044/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/022509-1.aspx)

we use [this one](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/09/The-CodeExpressionBuilder.aspx) for lots of similar tasks

This will allow you to write code like

```
<uc:Template ID="Template" runat="server" Package="<%$ Code : TemplateParams.SimpleSearch %>" />
```